# Firebase - Server Side Function onUpdate()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am quite new to firebase and wanted to ask your help for something:
I found out that firebase runs server side functions on certain events. One of those functions is `onUpdate()`.

So what I want to achieve is the following:
`onUpdate()` -> Sort documents in collection by score -> Assign rank based on position after sorting `(1, 2, 3, etc.)`

Any tips on how to do this?

*PS: The database can grow up to 1 Mio.+ documents so I am not quite sure if its an efficient way to do this. Every other way where I assign a rank by score is either too heavy on the client side, not real time or costs insane amounts of money.*

**Edit:**
As Angus Tay pointed out, I don't need to worry about performance, so that's out of the way.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [**MongoDB NoSQL Documentation**](https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-scale):

> **Scalability** is **not just about speed**. It's about 3 different metrics,  which often work together:
>
> **Cluster Scale.** Distributing the database across 100+ nodes, often in
>   multiple data centers
>
> **Performance Scale**. Sustaining 100,000+ database read and writes per
>   second while maintaining strict latency SLAs
>
> **Data Scale**. Storing 1 billion+ documents in the database

In **Firebase Database** (Realtime DB / Cloud Firestore), ***performance*** and ***scalability*** are not issues even the database has grown towards billions of documents.

**NoSQL** databases support **auto-sharding**, meaning that they **natively** and **automatically spread data across an arbitrary number of servers**, without **requiring the application to even be aware of the composition of the server pool**. Data and query load are automatically balanced across servers, and when a server goes down, it can be quickly and transparently replaced with no application disruption.

Therefore, you don't have to worry about the performance.

**UPDATE**

After the fundamental, back to your problem:

> onUpdate() -> Sort documents in collection by score -> Assign rank based on position after sorting (1, 2, 3, etc.)

**Yes**, you can achieve it but it is **not recommended**, as the **cost** of querying it is **very high** since you are using the firebase cloud services, each query counts even you make a call!  Here is a thread about [How we spent 30k USD in Firebase in less than 72 hours](https://hackernoon.com/how-we-spent-30k-usd-in-firebase-in-less-than-72-hours-307490bd24d).  There is a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lb-Pnytoi-8&t=269s) on how you can prevent this problem, but it is in Angular.

**Recommendation (Client -Server):**

1. Make a collection to store all the records documents
2. Example: Records(documents)-  highscore(field-array), besttime(field-array)
3. 1st query get the info you want (highscore) store in your client side when app launch
4. Check the score with the highscore stored earlier.
5. if higher then you update that document's field only instead of updating multiple documents

Usually, we don't purely do in server, even in server, we will build a front end which makes it the client, so ya, hope it give you an idea.

**Additional note:**

One of the purpose NoSQL is created is to avoid the relational database model as it may not be the best solution for all situations.

Don't limit your thinking in NoSQL, you have many ways to structure your database, be creative, there are always multiple solutions in NoSQL

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer :) What way would you recommend when it comes to giving ranks to users based on a score? In a way in which i dont need to pay 30.000$ :P